# Youtube causes black screen

Tags: 14.04, flash, youtube

Whenever I try to load any youtube video(HTML or otherwise), the entire screen goes black. The OS is still running, and the video is still playing the sound, but the screen is black. I tried uninstalling libx264, getting pepper-flash, re-installing flash, enabling the "override software rendering list" flag in chrome, and rebooting.

This happened after I was installing extra libx264 packages to fix a screenshare program(that didn't work). What can I do to fix this?? I have libx264-142 installed now.

Comment: What's your graphics card brand/model and what driver are you using?

Comment: My GPU is an integrated model on an intel core duo.

Comment: The driver is the default linux VGA, there are no linux drivers for this ancient thing.